# UITableViewCells not being drawn to the screen while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController to load a series of local objects from my CoreData store. After the objects have been loaded, I'm attempting to scroll the main UITableView down so that the last row is visible of the bottom of the screen. However, when I call this method, the top-most row or rows are not visible, yet when the tableview is moved by a couple of pixels by the user, the cell(s) re-appear. Please can you tell me why this is happening?

```
- (void) scrollToBottomAnimated:(BOOL) animated {
    if ([self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects].count > 0) {
        NSInteger section = [self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
        NSInteger item = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] - 1;
        NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:item inSection:section];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:animated];
    }
}
```

This annotated screenshot summarises what should be going on: http://d.pr/i/VNyE+

Edit - truncated -viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"My Notes"];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"870-smile"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showLoginOrProfile:)]];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[PSSpaceCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:PSSpaceCellReuseIdentifier];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[PSReusableHeaderView class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:PSSpaceHeaderReuseIdentifier];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil]) {
        NSLog(@"Error performing fetch: %@", error);
    }
    [self scrollToBottomAnimated:NO];
}

- (UITableView *) tableView {
    if (_tableView == nil) {
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - [self toolbar].frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        [_tableView setDelegate:self];
        [_tableView setDataSource:self];
        [_tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
        [_tableView setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack];
        [_tableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
        [_tableView setSectionFooterHeight:0];
        [_tableView setKeyboardDismissMode:UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive];
    }
    return _tableView;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PSSpaceCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PSSpaceCellReuseIdentifier];
    PSSpace *space = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [space setLeadsBeingLoaded:[self.spaceUIDsGettingLeads containsObject:[space spaceUID]]];
    [space setHasLeads:[self leadsAvailableForSpace:space]];
    [cell setSpace:space];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do mean atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom ? the text in your the question seems to indicate that you do.

Comment: @danh I'm more worried about the cell not appearing than the scroll position. UITableViewScrollPositionTop works fine for what I'm looking to achieve.

Comment: @max_ Is it possible you're calling `scrollToBottomAnimated:` from a background thread?  You can test this by dispatching to the main queue to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @AaronBrager I assumed that, however it doesn't seem to make a difference. I just used gcd to call it on the main thread, however it's scrolling down too far this time. I've also tried dispatch_after but that caused the same issue.

Comment: The fact that it's having any effect at all indicates you might have a threading issue.

Comment: @AaronBrager that's weird because the method that's calling `scrollToBottomAnimated:` is called directly from the viewDidLoad and it's callback is called on the same thread.

Comment: @AaronBrager if I call the following before `scrollToBottomAnimated:`, it returns 1 showing that it's running on the main thread: `NSLog(@"%d", [[NSThread mainThread] isEqual:[NSThread currentThread]]);`

Comment: Alas, my hunch is disproven.

Comment: @AaronBrager any other ideas?

Comment: Set the `backgroundColor` of your table to yellow, so you can see if/when its `frame` is changing?  Post your code from cellForRow…, numberOfRows… numberOfSections, etc.

Comment: @AaronBrager If I set the background colour to yellow, the tableview's frame is set to yellow as expected. The area that the cell should be appearing in is transparent. I've added some code.

Comment: @AaronBrager I'm confident that it's not related to the custom cell because if I return a UITableViewCell instead, the error persists.

Comment: Ok, so -performSelector:@selector(scrollToBottomAnimated:) works perfectly, however calling the method directly doesn't...

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but it looks like your method to create the cell is the older one where you have to initialize the cell if it does not exist. I think it could make a difference when the tableview is reusing cells while scrolling. You could try using the new method to see if it helps:
PSSpaceCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PSSpaceCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: @HobbestheTige hm good point, unfortunately hasn't made a difference though, cells still aren't displaying at the top of the table.

Comment: @max_ Two things: 1. Are you using the new iOS 7 row height estimation facility? (`tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`) If so, that is almost certainly the issue as there are bugs with Apple's implementation when scrolling to the top or bottom of table views. 2. If not, I suggest trying to move the call to `scrollToBottomAnimated:` from `viewDidLoad:` to `viewWillAppear:` (or `viewDidAppear:`). The reason is because the table view has not yet gone through a layout pass until then. (That might explain why using `performSelector:` worked, as the call was pushed to the next run loop.)

Comment: @max_ I'm willing to bet that your problem is fixed by suggestion #2. My theory why you're seeing a couple of cells missing is because the table view is loaded initially with a frame size to fit inside a 3.5" screen, and doesn't layout to the 4" screen until after `viewDidLoad:` is called. And of course, for whatever reason (maybe Apple's bug) the table view doesn't redraw correctly after increasing in height. That would explain why you have whitespace/unrendered cells that looks about the height difference between the 3.5" and 4" screens.

Comment: @smileyborg Looks like I owe you some reputation! -estimatedhHeightForRow... is the cause, and I've filed a bug report to hopefully fix this issue. Thanks for the suggestions, and solving the bane of my existence for the past few days!

Comment: @max_ Good to hear. That issue is hopefully fixed in 7.1 but I haven't tested yet in the latest beta to see. Anyways...posted a more complete answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21051595/796419

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the new iOS 7 row height estimation facility (using the `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, or setting the `estimatedRowHeight` property on the table view), you're unfortunately running into bugs with Apple's implementation when scrolling to the top or bottom of table views.

See this thread for a discussion I had with another developer about the same issue, as well as some possible workarounds:

https://github.com/caoimghgin/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout/issues/13

I've filed a Radar with Apple on this too (15283329).

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code, I can say, "what if" if the below statement fails to return a reusableCell in method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    /// what will happen if this returns a nil ?

    PSSpaceCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PSSpaceCellReuseIdentifier];
    ...
    ...
}
```

Please provide it a way to make a new cell if the reusable is not available like this .

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PSSpaceCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PSSpaceCellReuseIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[PSSpaceCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:PSSpaceCellReuseIdentifier];
    }
    PSSpace *space = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [space setLeadsBeingLoaded:[self.spaceUIDsGettingLeads containsObject:[space spaceUID]]];
    [space setHasLeads:[self leadsAvailableForSpace:space]];
    [cell setSpace:space];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
```

I hope that solves the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fix the issue. Having registered the class of the cell in the -vdl, there is no need to allocate the cell manually. Furthermore, after putting an NSLog in the -cellForRow... method, the dequeued cell is never nil.

Comment: Let me try this on a sample data & I will let you know.

Comment: as I said, it does not work and would never work because of the registration of the cell's class in the view did load method. This question has been solved.

Comment: I was able to get results with your code as I was having table creation in my viewdidLoad. As you said, may be your class is registering for UITableViewCell in viewDidLoad, could be problem. Can you elaborate, how it was fixed.